# how to web scrape the data from this site?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I would like to get the 8 years of data (graph 'Encours des parts référencées') from this [site](https://www.quantalys.com/espace/518).
I don't know I can find the data. I inspect the site but don't get see them. I would like to know where they are and how to get them and what api should I use ?
Here's a [image of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RALL0.png)

I tried:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
```

but after that I don't know what to do

Any help would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored in the page in Json form. To extract it to pandas dataframe you can do:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.quantalys.com/espace/518"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("#chartEncours8a input")["value"]
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['dataProvider'])
df['unit'] = data['valueAxes'][0]['unit']
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   category  column-1   unit
0      2015     41.02   Mrd€
1      2016     44.92   Mrd€
2      2017     43.44   Mrd€
3      2018     31.58   Mrd€
4      2019     25.30   Mrd€
5      2020     25.26   Mrd€
6      2021     25.55   Mrd€
7      2022     19.57   Mrd€
```

Comment: How did you find the data ? I looked for them for hours...

Comment: @jacques I pressed `Ctrl + U` to show the source code of the page and searched for one of the values found on the graph.

Comment: I am sorry I tried to find the data with inspect but can't find it

Comment: @jacques Don't inspect the data in web developer tools, search directly in HTML source code (`Ctrl + U`)